# location of file in Resources C#

Tags: c#, powershell

as in this photo I added a ps1 file in resources and I add it to my code... but not working

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you copying the ps1 file to the bin dir during build? What is the working directory when running the app?

Comment: @gunr2171 i am testing it not working but if i put it in any location on device it will work.
just wanna call it from Resources

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful It's C# ..... and yes it's in Resources folder

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by:

1. changing the property "Copy To OUTPUT Directory" to "Copy always",
   and
2. changing the code for .ps1 file path to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\\Resources\\TEST1.ps1"`

[image]